# "I made a challenge for/to myself"

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following is correct?

> I made a challenge to myself
>   I made a challenge for myself
>   I made myself a challenge

Comment: Why not 'I challenged myself'?

Comment: I mean diffucult task. What whould be better? Just "I challenged"?

Comment: *I gave myself a challenge*?

Comment: Either Kris’ or bib’s suggestion will indicate that you are (intentionally) the source of the challenge. If you want to indicate a challenge that you did *not* create, you might say "I was challenged (by...)" or "(The situation) challenged me." Be careful, though, not to make your statement too general, as the statement "I am challenged" on its own is used to communicate a persistent mental impairment that has the tasks of everyday life present a constant challenge. Providing more context around what exactly you wish to say may garner more satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 3):

There's no grammatical principle saying any of OP's alternatives are "incorrect", but none of them are particularly common...

> *I made a challenge to myself* ([22 hits in Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what%20would%20you%20say%20to%20the%20idea%20that%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22I%20made%20a%20challenge%20to%20myself%22&tbm=bks))
>    *I made a challenge for myself* ([3 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what%20would%20you%20say%20to%20the%20idea%20that%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22I%20made%20a%20challenge%20for%20myself%22&tbm=bks))
>    *I made myself a challenge* ([25 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what%20would%20you%20say%20to%20the%20idea%20that%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22I%20made%20myself%20a%20challenge%22&tbm=bks))

Idiomatically, we're more likely to say...

> *I **set myself** a challenge* ([320 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22america%20sent%20her%20soldiers%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22I%20set%20myself%20a%20challenge%22&tbm=bks))

---

It's worth pointing out that in many if not most contexts we're even *more* likely to say...

> *I set myself a **goal*** ([2330 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22america%20sent%20her%20soldiers%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22I%20set%20myself%20a%20goal%22&tbm=bks))

(in which context it's important to note that we almost never [***make*** ourselves a goal](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22america%20sent%20her%20soldiers%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22I%20made%20myself%20a%20goal%22&tbm=bks)).

Answer (score 0):

Your first and third are equivalent, two different ways of saying the same thing.  The second one is a bit different.  "To myself" has the feeling of "in my direction", whereas "for myself" has the feeling of "on my behalf".

As bib has pointed out it's rather more common to say "I gave a challenge" than "I made a challenge."